# Krishna marrying sixteen thousand royal maidens

Tags: krishna, bhagavata-purana, marriage, sex, narakasura

Consider the [following](https://innerschool.org/spb/sb/10/59/en1) slokas from Srimad Bhagavatam

> SB 10.59.32: Sukadeva Gosvami said: Thus entreated by Goddess Bhumi in
> words of humble devotion, the Supreme Lord bestowed fearlessness upon
> her grandson and then entered Bhaumasura's palace, which was filled
> with all manner of riches.
>
> SB 10.59.33: **There Lord Krishna saw sixteen thousand royal maidens,
> whom Bhauma had taken by force from various kings.**
>
> SB 10.59.34: The women became enchanted when they saw that most
> excellent of males enter. In their minds they each accepted Him, who
> had been brought there by destiny, as their chosen husband.
>
> SB 10.59.35: With the thought "May providence grant that this man
> become my husband," each and every princess absorbed her heart in
> contemplation of Krishna.
>
> SB 10.59.36: The Lord had the princesses arrayed in clean, spotless
> garments and then sent them in palanquins to Dvaraka, together with
> great treasures of chariots, horses and other valuables.
>
> SB 10.59.37: Lord Krishna also dispatched sixty-four swift white
> elephants, descendants of Airavata, who each sported four tusks.
>
> ....................................................................
> ....................................................................
> ....................................................................
> ....................................................................
> ....................................................................
> ....................................................................
>
> SB 10.59.42: **Then the imperishable Supreme Personality, assuming a
> separate form for each bride, duly married all the princesses
> simultaneously, each in her own palace**.
>
> SB 10.59.43: The Lord, performer of the inconceivable, constantly
> remained in each of His queens' palaces, which were unequaled and
> unexcelled by any other residence. There, although fully satisfied
> within Himself, **He enjoyed with His pleasing wives, and like an
> ordinary husband He carried out His household duties.**
>
> SB 10.59.44: **Thus those women obtained as their husband the husband of
> the goddess of fortune,** although even great gods like Brahma do
> not know how to approach Him. With ever-increasing pleasure they
> experienced loving attraction for Him, exchanged smiling glances with
> Him and reciprocated with Him in ever-fresh intimacy, replete with
> joking and feminine shyness.
>
> SB 10.59.45: Although the Supreme Lord's queens each had hundreds of
> maidservants, they chose to personally serve the Lord by approaching
> Him humbly, offering Him a seat, worshiping Him with excellent
> paraphernalia, bathing and massaging His feet, giving Him pan to chew,
> fanning Him, anointing Him with fragrant sandalwood paste, adorning
> Him with flower garlands, dressing His hair, arranging His bed,
> bathing Him, and presenting Him with various gifts.

From the above solkas it is clear that Narakasura forcefully took women and Krishna married all of them individually after killing Narakasura. He did all activities as normal husband.

My doubts are:

1. It is said that sixteen thousand women are royal maidens. **Are they virgin? If yes, then why did Narakasura took them by force from various kings**?
2. Is it allowed for some/ all person(s) to marry a women, who lost her celibacy or virginity?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79927/discussion-on-question-by-hanugm-krishna-marrying-sixteen-thousand-royal-maidens).

Answer (score 4):

A partial answer only.

> 2) Is it allowed for some/ all person(s) to marry a women, who lost
>   her celibacy or virginity?

As per the Smritis, not allowed.

> Manu Smriti 8.226. **The nuptial texts are applied solely to virgins,**
>   (and) nowhere among men to females who have lost their virginity, **for
>   such (females) are excluded from religious ceremonies.**

Also, we have:

> Manu Smriti 8.205. He who gives (a damsel in marriage), having first
>   openly declared her blemishes, whether she be insane, or afflicted
>   with leprosy, or have lost her virginity, is not liable to punishment

So, concealing (before marriage) the fact that the girl is not a virgin is also a punishable offence.